# Angular UI Select2 in the Bootstrap Navigation Bar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, jquery-select2, angular-ui

Select2 of the Angular-UI in Bootstrap navigation bar is giving error

```
TypeError: Object [[object HTMLInputElement]] has no method 'is'
```

Please refer to the http://plnkr.co/edit/yCG5M9

Comment: please explain your answer in more detail.

Comment: @jm-'s answer is correct. I've added an explanation to his post.

Answer (score 1):

You need to load jQuery before AngularJS

Just change the order to

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.3/angular.min.js"></script>
```

**EDIT** (blesh): This is because if angular doesn't see JQuery as it's loading, then the `tElm` (angular element) argument being passed into that `compile` function is a jqLite object. If Angular sees JQuery has been loaded *first*, the `tElm` will be a full JQuery object, and `is()` will be available.

Comment: This is the correct answer, I just added an explanation of *why* it's the correct answer.

Comment: But After changing the order of the script import Bootstrap navigation collapse does not work. The collapse button that comes for responsive design does not work. Please see the updated link http://plnkr.co/edit/yCG5M9