# angularUI ui-select2 directive not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-select2, angular-ui

I've been banging my head against the wall with this, so I've reduced it to the bare minimum:

**index.html:**

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
    <body ng-controller="main">

        <select ui-select2>
            <option>12451</option>
            <option>23435</option>
            <option>3456</option>
        </select>

        <!-- Scripts loaded here. See the plunker -->

    </body>
</html>
```

**app.js:**

```
angular
    .module('myApp', ['ui'])
    .controller('main', function (){});
```

Here's the link to the Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/kXnHPzBt7apRc7EivLp8?p=preview

I think I'm doing it all right, but it just refuses to initialize the `select2`.

Here's the error I get:

> Object [[object HTMLSelectElement]] has no method 'is'

Here's a screenshot of the error:

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to load jQuery before AngularJS and apparently `select2.js` before Angular-ui

The following order works fine

```
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>          
<script src="select2.js"></script>
<script src="angular.js"></script>  
<script src="angular-ui.js"></script>
```

Check the plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/sAGfzmNdykEnqlH40gNf?p=preview

---

Check this other answer: [Angular UI Select2 in the Bootstrap Navigation Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13745124/angular-ui-select2-in-the-bootstrap-navigation-bar/13745664#13745664)